# find created on returns always 0

Tags: mongodb, date, find

i want to find the counts created with mongoDB between 2 dates :

```
db.getCollection('annonces').find({created_on: {$gte: "2015-06-23T11:11:05.000Z", $lt: "2015-08-23T11:11:05.000Z"}})
```

but it is always returning a null value while the database contains one :

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55b0cbc947a60eb012281005"),
    "name" : "Test",
    "type" : "video",
    "date_ajout" : ISODate("2015-07-23T11:11:05.000Z")

}
```

Comment: `date_ajout` appears to be in French. It should be changed to `created_on` which is the query param you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a date range query with **[`ISODate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#return-date)** constructor which returns a Date object using the **[`ISODate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#return-date)** wrapper. Try the following:

```
db.getCollection('annonces').find({
    "date_ajout": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2015-06-23T11:11:05.000Z"), 
        "$lt": ISODate("2015-08-23T11:11:05.000Z")
    }
})
```

Another way to do this is to create a JavaScript date object using the **[`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)** constructor that returns a Date object using the ISODate() wrapper:

```
var start = new Date(2015, 5, 23, 11, 11, 5);
var end = new Date(2015, 7, 23, 11, 11, 5);

db.annonces.find({"date_ajout": {"$gte": start, "$lt": end}});
```